# How to install aircrack

Tags: 14.04, aircrack-ng

Can I get help installing aircrack-ng-1.2-beta3/aircrackng-1.1 in a detailed form? Im using Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the answer by BillGates, Aircrack-ng 1.1 is in the repos.

To install `1.2-beta3`, you need to download the source:

```
wget http://download.aircrack-ng.org/aircrack-ng-1.2-beta3.tar.gz
```

Extract it:

```
tar xzf aircrack-ng-1.2-beta3.tar.gz
```

Change into the directory:

```
cd aircrack-ng-1.2-beta3
```

Make sure you have the `build-essentials` package installed to be able to compile programs. Then start compiling:

```
make
```

You might encounter some missing libraries along the way, for example you might see something like this:

```
common.mak:85: *** Cannot find development files for any supported version of libnl. install either libnl1 or libnl3..  Stop.
```

To solve these errors, install all missing *development* libraries, for example, `libnl-3-dev` for this one.

When it's done, you can run Aircrack from this directory or install it system-wide:

```
sudo make install
```

Comment: Seems somme libraries are needed, in my case :
    sudo apt-get install libnl-3-dev libnl-genl-3-dev libssl-dev

Answer (score 4):

Aircrack-ng 1.1 is in the [official Ubuntu Repository](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=aircrack&searchon=names&suite=trusty&section=all)

Open a terminal by pressing Ctrl+Alt+ T

Then copy and paste the following command in the terminal.

Then press Enter.

```
sudo apt-get install aircrack-ng
```

---

Edit :

To resolve your problem, run a update before installation.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: That's one of the many commands that I tried looks like aircrack is no longer in the universal reposotories.

Comment: Sorry and thanks for the help it did work looks like i tried more complicated codes.

Comment: @user298130 welcome.

Comment: Ok so now that ive installed it i cant seem to find an icon or anything to run the program any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

I formatted my computer and obviously I had to reinstall all programs. When installed aircrack-ng again, I realized that there are more dependencies to install, some are suggestions and others are installed by default.

```
sudo su
```

enter your password,
then install all dependencies, Here the list

```
apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev libnl-3-dev libnl-genl-3-dev
dpkg-dev g++ g++-4.8 libc-dev-bin libc6-dev libstdc++-4.8-dev zlib1g-dev
debian-keyring g++-multilib g++-4.8-multilib gcc-4.8-doc libstdc++6-4.8-dbg
glibc-doc libstdc++-4.8-doc libalgorithm-merge-perl libssl-doc 
libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl
```

after that, update your system

```
apt-get update
```

when this install is done you can start the aircrack install, like this

```
wget http://download.aircrack-ng.org/aircrack-ng-1.2-rc4.tar.gz
tar -zxvf aircrack-ng-1.2-rc4.tar.gz
cd aircrack-ng-1.2-rc4
make
make install
```

and you will get aircrack-ng up and running. Now the success is guaranteed

Answer (score -1):

To install Aircrack-ng 1.2 rc3-4 from the official Ubuntu Repository,

you have to install the source of  wily, xenial, or yakkety

to check the current source list:

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list
```

to add xenial source list:

```
cat >> /etc/apt/sources.list
```

in the new line copy and past the following line

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted universe multiverse
```

then press on ctrl+J and ctrl+D, for new line and to finish editting

then update the repository

```
sudo apt-get update
```

then install aircreack-ng 1.2 rc3-4

```
apt-get install aircrack-ng
```

Comment: This a very bad way to add `xenial` repo. It is harmful if done on another ubuntu version. It is also harmful on Xenial.

Comment: you can remove the repo after installing aircrack-ng