# Errors while installing aircrack-ng

Tags: software-installation, aircrack-ng

```
make -C src all
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/ibrahim/aircrack-ng-1.2-beta3/src'
gcc -g -W -Wall -O3 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REVISION=0  -DCONFIG_LIBNL30 -I/usr/include/libnl3   -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-array-bounds -Iinclude   -c -o aircrack-ng.o aircrack-ng.c
In file included from aircrack-ng.c:69:0:
crypto.h:50:26: fatal error: openssl/hmac.h: No such file or directory
 #include <openssl/hmac.h>
                          ^
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [aircrack-ng.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ibrahim/aircrack-ng-1.2-beta3/src'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: i have made this process with my last installation and does work perfect...try it http://askubuntu.com/a/585654/378928

Answer (score 1):

The [installation page](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=install_aircrack) tells you what dependencies you need. This one is fulfilled by:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

---

This is already packaged in trusty/universe (version 1.0) so if dependencies haven't changed that much a good tip can be to just let `apt-get build-dep` help you:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep aircrack-ng
```

That will download all the dependencies required to build the repo version. Might not be *everything* you need but it should get you most of the way.